# bundle install thinks it is using a ruby version I don't have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rvm, bundler

Trying to do bundle install and I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.7
```

The thing is I don't have ruby 2.6.3 installed (OS Catalina)

Using rvm list I get:

```
code
➜  cooper git:(id_43310_add_pr_comments_notification) ✗ rvm list
=> ruby-2.2.7 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.3.8 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

➜  ✗ rvm uninstall 2.6.3
ruby-2.6.3 - #already gone
➜  ✗ rvm remove 2.6.3
ruby-2.6.3 - #already gone
Using /Users/noammansur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8
```

```
which ruby
/Users/noammansur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/bin/ruby
echo $path
/Users/noammansur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin /Users/noammansur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@global/bin /Users/noammansur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/bin /Users/noammansur/.rvm/bin /Users/noammansur/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.7p470 (2017-03-28 revision 58194) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

but this doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am pretty sure you *do* have Ruby 2.6.3 installed, since that is shipped with Catalina.

Comment: MacOS has preinstalled ruby, you can check it just typing `ruby -v` in your `bash`

Comment: Have you also tried to change the local version of ruby for that project to what you want?

Comment: So apparently I do have it. What can I do about the bundle install failing?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.6.3 comes preinstalled in MacOS Catalina, so your problem should be coming from damaged rvm installation or PATH. Start with checking `ruby -v` and `which ruby`.

When rvm is working you'll get something like:

```sh
$ which ruby
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby

$ echo $PATH
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin:
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global/bin:
/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin:
/Users/<username>/.rvm/bin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

in other case:

```sh
$ rvm use system
Now using system ruby.

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/<username>/.rvm/bin
```

Check if you (or something) modified your profile scripts (.profile, .bashrc, zshrc and so on, depends on your shell and setup) and overrided PATH, also look for presence of rvm init there:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: @NoamMansur also see `/usr/bin/ruby -v`

Comment: `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]`
So how can I change that/make bundle not use that?

Comment: @NoamMansur that's system ruby 2.6.3 in question, that runs when for some reason when rvm one does not

Comment: so any suggestions?

Comment: @NoamMansur dig into why bundler runs under it, this may be because your rvm ruby has bundler missing for some reason and next one in path is selected, or `bundle` command with `/user/bin/ruby` shebang etc.